# Can't good editors have their edits automatically approved even though they don't have enough reputation?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editing, suggested-edits

The title pretty much says it all. I do a lot of edits and the vast majority of them gets accepted after the peer reviewing.

Couldn't the editors who have like over 90% of their edits on the questions and answers of the other people accepted get the right to edit *without* the peer review?

It would be useful, and, I'd find it awesome because I'm a perfectionist and want everything tidy and nice as soon as possible.

Comment: Since I'm sure it will come up, the edit that you had made today was too minor.  You had corrected something that was, in fact, already correct, and the post probably would have been fine with the actual grammatical error intact. While there was absolutely no harm done in that case, and I encourage you to keep editing, this is the type of instruction that can be provided gently through the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has come up on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) before, and been declined.

Once you get to 2,000 reputation, the thought is that you are now well-versed and trustworthy enough in the workings of the site to be able to edit without having your edits reviewed. Virtually all privileges on Stack Exchange are tied to your reputation score, and the Developers seem disinclined to complicate that by adding another path to getting privileges.

Of course, if you're bad at editing, (and the reviewers are paying attention) you'll get suspended from adding more suggested edits, possibly for a long time.